# Creation of maximum size file in C: drive (OS drive) fails

Tags: c, windows, winapi, file-io, privileges

I have developed a disk and file wiping software (using WIN32 api) which also contains option of wiping drive's free space. I do this by creating a file which is size of drive's free space available and then I write random bytes (Applying various standard wiping schemes) on that file.

My problem is that It works well on on every other drive except on the drive which has windows operating system installed (in my case, it is C:). It gives "Not enough disk space" error although the said drive has lots of free space available. My program runs with administrative privileges. Is it some kind of privileges issue? Do I need to give more privileges to my program even after running it with administrator? I would want to do it programatically using winapi.

I am testing mostly on NTFS file system. I am creating file using CreateFile winapi call and to make sure to create exact size of file equaling available free space, I am using fragmentation api to get free space and then using SetEndOfFile winapi method to extend the size of file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the real error returned by `GetLastError`?  (Those are numeric, not text)  What filesystem is this?  What was the actual size of the file you tried to create?  How large a file are you able to create?  No one can help you with the information you have provided.

Comment: More to the point, allocating a file over all the free space is no longer a useful approach to disk wiping.  This method may actually harm solid state disks, and may leave significant amounts of data untouched due to modern block remapping algorithms.

Comment: With a similar problem years ago, the "disk free space" was advisory at best and of course it is dynamic.  So making a file that size had troubles.  Instead used 50% the system reported "disk free space" and perform repeated calls eventually consuming the disk.  Got close enough for government work.

BTW, wiped with random data, not zeros.

Comment: GetLastError gives ERROR_DISK_FULL error. I am able to create the file of size of max free bytes on either NTFS or FAT file systems on drives other than C.

Comment: Wild guess, might it have something to do with the windows swap file?

Comment: How are you obtaining the disk free space? Some methods will produce an incorrect value because they do not account for certain hidden features.

Comment: @chux - yeah, I did that with command-line concat - doubling the size of a small garbage file until fail, then halving, rinse, repeat.

Comment: How are you creating the file? Free space on system partition is probably going to change pretty often (temporary files, etc.) and if it shrinks in between getting its amount and actually creating a file of that size of course it's going to fail.

Comment: Is that disk FAT32 and are you trying to create a file over 4GB?

Comment: I dont have code at this time. I'll try to post it. I am testing mostly on NTFS file system. I am creating file using CreateFile winapi call and to make sure to create exact size of file equaling available free space, I am using fragmentation api to get free space and then using SetEndOfFile winapi method to extend the size of file.

Comment: @JewelThief You have specified some valuable debugging info in comments. Please [edit] your question to include it, so people trying to answer can find it conveniently.

Comment: Disk space is required to keep track of things beyond the file contents. For example, the file system needs disk space to keep track of the file name, the security attributes, the location of the file data, the journal entries...

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't handle running out of disk space well, so it wouldn't surprise me if the system reserves some disk space ordinary users, even administrators can't use. However regardless of whether that is true or not, your scheme is flawed. It's easily possible for the amount of space allocated to change in between the the time you find out how much space is free and you try to allocate it all. And even it works, things might start breaking because the disk is full, even if only for a short while.

Since you're already using the defragmentation API, I'd use it to wipe all the clusters on the disk without trying to allocate them all once. First create a file that fills up most of the disk space, but leaves plenty of room for other processes to allocate files. Then use `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP` to get the bitmap of unallocated sectors, and `FSCTL_MOVE_FILE` to move clusters from the file you created into the free clusters found in the bitmap. You'll need to be ready for `FSCTL_MOVE_FILE` to fail because something allocated one of the clusters marked as free. In that case I would keep halving the number of clusters you were moving at once until it worked. If it fails with only one cluster, than you know that it's the cluster (or one of the clusters) that's been allocated.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
// unalloc_start and unalloc_len describe an unallocated region in the free space bitmap
wipe_unallocated_clusters(hwipefile, unalloc_start, unalloc_len, max_chunk_len) {
    unalloc_vcn = unalloc_start
    unalloc_end = unalloc_start + unalloc_len
    max_chunck_len = max(max_chunk_len, unalloc_len)
    clen = max_chunk_len
    while(unalloc_vcn < unalloc_end) {
        clen = max(clen, unalloc_end - unalloc_vcn)
        while (fsctl_move_file(hwipefile, 0, unalloc_vcn, clen) == FAILED) {
            if (clen == 1) {
                unalloc_vcn++   // skip over allocated cluster
                continue
            }
            clen /= 2  // try again with half as many clusters
        }
        unalloc_vcn += clen
        clen = max(clen * 2, max_chunk_len)  // double the clusters if it worked
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice. I will surely give your method a try.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing some code and specific values that fail would be nice, but I'll try to use my psychic powers. I have two theories.

1) your file size exceeds maximum file size for the filesystem on C:. FAT16 supports up to 2GB, FAT32 supports up to 4GB files.

2) you have too many files in your root directory. There are some reports that Windows FAT32 implementation supports only 1000 file entries in the root directory.

Comment: I dont have code at this time. I'll try to post it. I am testing mostly on NTFS file system. I am creating file using CreateFile winapi call and to make sure to create exact size of file equaling available free space, I am using fragmentation api to get free space and then using SetEndOfFile winapi method to extend the size of file.